# How to use Accept-Encoding in Guzzle Http client

Tags: php, php-curl, guzzle6

I use this php library http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html to get content from remote site. (version 6)

I'm testing randomly two url.

1. URL:
   https://www.asos.com/jack-jones/jack-jones-leather-chelsea-boot-in-black/prd/12700615?clr=pirate-black&colourWayId=16521640&SearchQuery=&cid=57743

code:

```
$url = 'https://www.asos.com/jack-jones/jack-jones-leather-chelsea-boot-in-black/prd/12700615?clr=pirate-black&colourWayId=16521640&SearchQuery=&cid=57743';

$request = $this->client->request('GET', $url, [
    'debug' => true,
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
        'Accept' => '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate'
    ]
]);
```

I use Accept-Encoding in url 1. If I didn't use Accept-Encoding, it wouldn't work.

2. URL: https://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=440775002&cid=5225&pcid=5225&vid=1&grid=pds_0_190_1&cpos=0&cexp=1321&cid=CategoryIDs%3D5225&cvar=9527&ctype=Listing&cpid=res19102206328645959183874#pdp-page-content

code:

```
$url = 'https://www.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=440775002&cid=5225&pcid=5225&vid=1&grid=pds_0_190_1&cpos=0&cexp=1321&cid=CategoryIDs%3D5225&cvar=9527&ctype=Listing&cpid=res19102206328645959183874#pdp-page-content';

$request = $this->client->request('GET', $url, [
    'debug' => true,
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0',
        'Accept' => '*/*'
    ]
]);
```

I don't use Accept-Encoding in url 2. If I used Accept-Encoding, it wouldn't work.

Both codes work fine, but I don't know how to decide when to put Accept-Encoding.

Don't you know how?

Or is there a better solution to download site content?

Comment: can you try both with `Accept-Encoding: *`?

Comment: tried, but doesn't work